# Stored procedure for generic MERGE

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a set of 10 tables in a database (`DB1`). And there are 10 tables in another database (`DB2`) with exact same schema on the same SQL Server 2008 R2 database server machine.

The 10 tables in `DB1` are frequently updated with data.

I intend to write a stored procedure that would run once every day for synchronizing the 10 tables in `DB1` with `DB2`. The stored procedure would make use of the `MERGE` statement.

Now, my aim is to make this as generic and parametrized as possible. That is, accommodate for more tables down the line... and accommodate different source and target DB names. Definitely no hard coding is intended.

This is my algorithm so far:

1. Have the database names as parameters
2. Have the first query within the stored procedure... result in giving the names of the 10 tables from a lookup table (this can be 10, 20 or whatever)
3. Have a generic `MERGE` statement that does the sync for each of the above set of tables (based on primary key?)

This is where I need more inputs on.

What is the best way to achieve this stored procedure? SQL syntax would be helpful.

Comment: If you really want to go this route you can use the MERGE statement. However, have you looked at replication. It seems you are trying to rewrite what replication already does.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar, to do that i used a string with a "skeleton" for the merge statement, then i retrieved the list of columns and the pks with a simple query on the sys views.

you could do something similar to build your merge statement, here's a sketch i wrote now as an example (I know it's horrible but i'm not going to write something decent at this hour, and it should give you a hint anyway :P )

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19383/10)

then you just need to execute it with the usual `sp_executesql` stored procedure
by the way, always pay attention when building command strings this way, it's not that secure